# How to compute expectation value $\langle e^{iH}\rangle$ for quadratic Hamiltonians?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, harmonic-oscillator, quantum-optics, coherent-states

I have a rather basic, but actually non-trivial question:

We consider a bosonic system with creation operators $\hat{a}_i^\dagger$ and annihilation operators $\hat{a}_j$ and vacuum state $|0\rangle$ with $\hat{a}_i|0\rangle=0$. We consider a quadratic Hamiltonian
\begin{align}
\hat{H}=\sum_{ij}(A_{ij}\hat{a}_i\hat{a}_j+A^*_{ij}\hat{a}^\dagger_i\hat{a}^\dagger_j+B_{ij}\hat{a}_i^\dagger\hat{a}_j)\,.
\end{align}
Hermiticity requires $B_{ij}=B^*_{ji}$. How can I compute the expectation value:
\begin{align*}
\langle 0|e^{i\hat{H}}|0\rangle
\end{align*}

*In many situations, it is useful to express the problem in terms of Hermitian quadrature operators $\hat{q}_i=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\hat{a}^\dagger_i+\hat{a}_j)$ and $\hat{p}_i=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\hat{a}^\dagger_i-\hat{a}_j)$ to define $\hat{\xi}^a=(\hat{q}_1,\dots,\hat{q}_N,\hat{p}_1,\dots,\hat{p}_N,)$, such that $$\hat{H}=\frac{1}{2}h_{ab}\hat{\xi}^a\hat{\xi}^b$$ with implied sums over $a$ and $b$. It is also useful to define the symplectic form $\Omega^{ab}$, such that $[\hat{\xi}^a,\hat{\xi}^b]=i\Omega^{ab}$, which gives rise to the symplectic generator $K^a{}_b=\Omega^{ac}h_{cb}$. We only require that $h_{ab}$ is symmetric and real.*

Comment: Do you know what $\hat H|0\rangle$ is?

Comment: @secavara: Yes, sure. I added the requirement.

Comment: @AaronStevens: Sure, I can write $\hat{H}|0\rangle$ as vector in the $N(N+1)/2$-dimensional space of 2-particle excitations. Note, however, that $\hat{H}$ may not be diagonalizable, which means that you cannot do a simple decomposition in eigenvectors!

Comment: @secavara $B$ is Hermitian, but not necessarily $A$. They will not commute in general.

Comment: @secavara No, $A$ does not need to be Hermitian. If you assume that $A$ and $B$ commute, you end up with the same problem for $H=\alpha (\hat{a}^\dagger)^2+\alpha^*(\hat{a})^2+\gamma \hat{a}^\dagger\hat{a}$, i.e., for a single mode. [I should say that I'm able to compute the expectation value up to an overall sign, which is due to the fact that quadratic Hamiltonians generate a representation of the metaplectic group, rather than the symplectic group. However, I was hoping that somebody has some reference where the calculation is done without invoking winding numbers and cocycles...]

Comment: @secavara Well, any antisymmetric part won't matter, so you can assume that $A$ is symmetric, because $\hat{H}$ only depends on the symmetric part.

Comment: It would help if you clarify all this in your question, in addition to the fact that you only care about the case $[A,B] \neq 0$. I'll help tidying up by erasing all my comments.

Comment: Do you know about Gaussian states?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: Yes, I do: $U=e^{iH}$ represents a symplectic matrix $M$. I can Cartan decompose $M=Tu$, where $\hat{T}=e^{i\hat{t}}$ is pure squeezing (no $\hat{a}_i^\dagger \hat{a}_j$ terms in $\hat{t}$) and $\hat{u}=e^{iH'}$ where $|0\rangle$ is the ground state of the quadratic Hamiltonian $H'$. However, it's only a projective representation, such that $e^{iH}=\pm e^{i\hat{t}}e^{iH'}$, so I'm missing the sign $\pm$ (embarrassing, I know) due to $U(M)$ being only a faithful representation of the metaplectic group. Do you know a simple reference/lecture notes, which treats the general case?

Comment: I believe you may diagonalize *B* by a unitary transformation and so reduce the 3rd term to a sum of disjoint oscillators with different eigenfrequencies, mapping the first two terms to a similar expression. So *B* is as good as a real diagonal matrix.

Comment: @LFH What I know is that overlaps of Gaussian pure states can only be determined up to a phase since what you define is in fact the density operator (which does not fix the phase).  However, you have |0><0| so the phase should be fine.  So my guess would be that there is no ambiguity, but I cannot tell for sure.  I'll try to think about it.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: Yes, exactly, if we wanted to compute the overlap of two Gaussian states described by their covariance matrices, the phase is undetermined because covariance matrices parametrize states (rays) rather than state vectors. However, if we fix the unitary, we also fix the phase relation, which can be computed in principle. Using representation theory I can also get most of the phase (see below), but not the sign.

Comment: Can't you fix the phase by looking at the differential $\langle0 |iH|0\rangle$? Or does the energy also have a $\pm1$ ambiguity?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I tried this, but may have not done the right thing. I thought that I could compare $\langle 0|i\hat{H}|0\rangle$ with $\langle 0| i \widehat{Q}|0\rangle$, where $\widehat{Q}$ is the quadratic operator associated to the symplectic Lie algebra element $Q=\log{M}$ (such that if $e^{i H}$ wraps around the metaplectic group, the sign is detected by the fact that $\widehat{Q}$ will differ from $H$ by some multiple of $2\pi$. But you may have something smarter in mind?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: Of course, in principle there is the following way: You can introduce a parameter $t$, such that $\langle 0|e^{-i t}|0\rangle=1$ at $t=0$. You can then apply the algorithm, I outlined below and increase $t\to 1$. If you plot the phase numerically, you will see a jump by $\pi$, which you can manually correct (by continuum argument). However, this would require this analysis at every step, while I was hoping to have some simpler formula just in terms of the coefficent matrix of the Hamiltonian...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using this [John Rawnsley: On the universal covering group of the real symplectic group](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/rawnsley.pdf), I found a relatively elegant way to write a partial solution, which makes clear where the sign ambiguity comes from. For this, we use the basis $\hat{\xi}^a=(\hat{q}_1,\dots,\hat{q}_N,\hat{p}_1,\dots,\hat{p}_N)$, such that the ground state covariance matrix $G^{ab}=\langle 0|\hat{\xi}^a\hat{\xi}^b+\hat{\xi}^b\hat{\xi}^a|0\rangle$ is the identity. We then define the associated complex structure and symplectic form
\begin{align}
G\equiv\begin{pmatrix}
1\!\!1 & 0\\
0 & -1\!\!1
\end{pmatrix}\,,\quad J\equiv\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\!\!1\\
-1\!\!1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\,,\quad \Omega\equiv\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\!\!1\\
-1\!\!1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
*I use different symbols here, because $J^a{}_b$ is a linear map and $\Omega^{ab}$ is a bilinear form, which only happen to be represented by the same matrix in this specific basis.*
The quadratic Hamiltonian is fully characterized by its symmetric coefficient matrix $h_{ab}$, such that $\hat{H}=\frac{1}{2}h_{ab}\hat{\xi}^a\hat{\xi}^b$. With this in hand, we define the symplectic algebra generator $K^a{}_b=\Omega^{ab}h_{bc}$ with the symplectic transformation
\begin{align}
M=e^{t K}=\begin{pmatrix}
A & B\\
C & D
\end{pmatrix}\,.
\end{align}
The expectation value is then given by (I derived it with the method of my previous answer based on the definitions of the Rawnsley paper)
\begin{align}
\langle 0|e^{-i t\hat{H}}|0\rangle=1/\sqrt{\det{\mathcal{C}_M}}\,,
\end{align}
where $\mathcal{C}_M$ is a complex $N$-by-$N$ matrix defined as follows: We first compute $C_M=\frac{1}{2}(M-JMJ)$, which commutes with $J$, i.e., it satisfies $[C_M,J]=0$. However, $C_M$ is a $2N$-by-$2N$ matrix, but because it commutes with $J$ (representing an imaginary unit with $J^2=-1\!\!1$) we can convert it to complex matrix $N$-by-$N$ matrix in the $(+i)$-eigenspace of $J$. We thus find
\begin{align}
C_M=\frac{M-JMJ}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
A+D & B-C\\
C-B & A+D
\end{pmatrix}\quad\Rightarrow\quad \mathcal{C}_M=\frac{A+D}{2}+i\frac{B-C}{2}\,.
\end{align}
Now we see exactly where the sign ambiguity comes from: The square root function $1/\sqrt{\det{\mathcal{C}_M}}$ has a branch cut and is thus ambiguous up to a sign. Of course, we can always determine the correct sign by hand: We start at $t=0$ with $\langle 0|e^{-i t\hat{H}}|0\rangle=1$ and then increase $t$ to our desired value, while choosing the square root $1/\sqrt{\det{\mathcal{C}_M}}$ in a continuous way.

**Example 1.** In the special case, where $[K,J]=0$, we also have $[M,J]=0$, such that $C_M=M=e^{Kt}$ with $A=D$ and $B=-C$. Therefore, we have $\mathcal{C}_M=A+i B$. In this case, $K$ is of the following form and we define $\mathcal{K}$
\begin{align}
K=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & k\\
-k & 0
\end{pmatrix}\quad\Rightarrow\quad\mathcal{K}=i k
\end{align}
where $k=\mathrm{diag}(\epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_N)$. We then have $\mathcal{C}_M=A+iB=e^{t\mathcal{K}}=e^{itk}$ as complex $N$-by-$N$ matrix. We can then compute the expectation value as
\begin{align}
\langle 0|e^{-i t\hat{H}}|0\rangle=1/\sqrt{\det{\mathcal{C}_M}}=1/\sqrt{\det{e^{it k}}}=e^{-\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}\log{ikt}}=e^{-\frac{it}{2}\mathrm{tr}(k)}=e^{-\frac{it}{2}\sum_i\omega_i}\,.
\end{align}
Here, we got rid of the sign ambiguity by using $\sqrt{\det{e^X}}=e^{\frac{1}{2}\log \det{e^X}}=e^{\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}{\log e^{X}}}$, where we set $\log e^X=X$ without taking branch cuts into account and thereby healing the ambiguity. The result is of course, trivially correct, because for $[J,K]=0$ the state $|0\rangle$ is the ground state of the Hamiltonian with vacuum energy $E_0=\frac{1}{2}\sum_i\omega_i$.

**Example 2.** The other case that I could treat was the setting where the Hamiltonian $\hat{H}=\sum_i\omega_i(\hat{n}_i+\frac{1}{2})$ has a ground state $|\{0,\dots,0\}\rangle=|0_1\rangle\dots|0_N\rangle$, i.e., it is a tensor product of squeezed 1-mode states, where the initial vacuum $|0\rangle=|0\rangle\dots|0\rangle$ is also a tensor product. Up to a complex phase, we can then relate $|0\rangle$ and $|n_i\rangle$ (arbitrary number excitations of the $n$-th mode of the Hamtiltonian) with a squeezing parameter $r_i$, such that
\begin{align}
|\langle 2n_i|0\rangle|^2=\frac{(2n)! \tanh^{2n_i}{r_i}}{2^{2n_i}(n_i!)^2\cosh{r_i}}\,.
\end{align}
This allows us to use a resolution of the identity, sum the series to find
\begin{align}
\langle 0|e^{-i t\hat{H}}|0\rangle&=\sum_{n_i,n'_j}\langle 0|\{n_1,\dots,n_N\}\rangle\langle\{n_1,\dots,n_N\}|e^{-i \hat{H}}|\{n_1',\dots,n_N'\}\rangle\langle\{n_1',\dots,n_N'\}|0\rangle\\
&=\prod_i\sum_{n_i}|\langle 2n_i|0\rangle|^2e^{-i \omega_i t(2n_i+\frac{1}{2})}\\
&=\prod_i\frac{e^{-\frac{i\omega_it}{2}}\mathrm{sech}(r_i)}{\sqrt{1-e^{-2i\omega_it}\tanh^2{r_i}}}\,.
\end{align}
However, I haven't really tested if the square root in the denominator has the same sign ambiguity.

**I have not been able to come up with a smart way to extract the sign in other cases, except manually taking $t$ to its desired value on requiring continuity of $\langle 0|e^{-i t\hat{H}}|0\rangle$ on the way...**

**Update:** I believe that I found a closed form solution of the problem that does not involve integration. It requires the use of the cocycle function $\eta(M_1,M_2)$ defined in John Rawnsley's paper from above (which can be evaluated with elementary matrix operation). In the end, we find that the correct complex phase is given by $e^{i \psi}$ with $\psi=\frac{1}{2}(\mathrm{tr}(uKu^{-1})+\eta(u,e^K)+\eta(ue^{K},u^{-1}))$, where $u$ is a symplectic transformation that brings $K$ into a standard form $\tilde{K}=uKu^{-1}$ in the same basis as $J$ takes its standard form. More precisely, we transform $K$, such that in its real eigenbasis (for complex eigenvalues we keep real blocks with antisymmetric pieces) the complex structure $J$ takes the same form $\Omega$. I may write this up as a more pedagogical note later on, but for now I hope that my solution is useful if somebody has the same question...

Answer (score 7):

There is a discussion of the evolution of a wavefunction  under your  general quadratic hamiltonian in the book by Guillemin and Sternberg "Symplectic methods in Physics." It's in their section on optics. I'm stuck at home because of the lockdown so I do not have my copy to hand. The only thing I have in my notes is the following that I copied from their text. It does discuss the phase  issue, but annoyingly with the same sign ambiguity that you have. I only give what I have to give you a sense of what is in G&S, so that you can decide  as to whether their book  is worth looking up.

Here is their quote: Let
$$
M= \left(\matrix{A&B\cr C&D}\right)\in {\rm Sp}(2n, {\mathbb R})
$$
Then the metaplectic projective representation on square integrable functions is given by
$$
U(M) \psi(x)=i^\#e^{-i\pi n/4} |\det B|^{-1/2} \frac 1{(2\pi)^{n/2}} \int e^{iW(x,y)}\psi(y) d^ny
$$
where
$$
W(x,y)=\frac 12 (xDB^{-1} x+ yB^{-1}Ay-2x(B^T)^{-1}y)
$$
and 
$\#$ is even if $\det B>0$ and odd if $\det B<0$.

Comment: Wonderful! I will definitely check it out. Thank you very much for the reference! It is clear that they can only specify up to a sign, because they define it in terms of $M$. Only if we really write the operator $e^{iH}$, the sign is fixed.

I made a bit of progress using cocycles on the universal covering group and maybe that's as good as one can do, but it's very good to check out references discussing the issue (haven't seen it in any other book / review on Gaussian states etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Start diagonalizing H. You can follow this:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.0787.pdf
Then use the power series of an exponential. You get the result in the diagonal basis. Make the inverse transformation and it is done.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion! However, $\hat{H}$ may not be diagonalizable. This is related to the fact that $\hat{H}$ represents a symplectic algebra element, which may not be diagonalizable. We can decompose $K=R+I+N$, where $R$ has real eigenvalues, $I$ has imaginary eigenvalues and $N$ is nilpotent. As pointed out by your reference, only if $R=N=0$, $\hat{H}$ can be diagonalized. I was hoping to find a solution for the general case, which I haven't found in the literature yet.

Just to give an example: A non-diagonalizable piece is for example $\hat{H}=\hat{q}^2-\hat{p}^2$.

Comment: I'm a bit lost with your notation. That is the usual Hamiltonian used in Gaussian quantum optics. Maybe you can look for Autonne-Takagi or Bloch-Messiah decompositions. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! Ok, let's assume I can diagonalize it, then I have $e^{i\sum_i\omega_i(\hat{n}_i+1/2)}$, where $\hat{n}_i$ are the number operators in the diagonal basis. Then I would need to compute $\sum_{n_1,\dots, n_N} e^{i\sum_i\omega_i(n_i+1/2)} |\langle \{n_i\}|0\rangle|^2$, where $|\{n_i\}\rangle$ are the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian and $|0\rangle$ our original vacuum (differing from $|0,\dots,0\rangle$). I'll see how far I get with that...

Comment: You need to apply the transformation to the vacuum too. Using q,p and Heisenberg is easier to see. Look at section II.b of https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.10055   But maybe this is a subcase of what you are trying to show.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Yes, of course, that was already implied (rather than acting with a tranformation on the vacuum, you can just think that $\langle \{0,\dots,0\}|0\rangle\neq 1$, because $|0\rangle$ is a different vacuum). In essence, you are just put in a resolution of the identity: $\langle 0|e^{-iH}|0\rangle=\sum_{n_i,n'_j}\langle 0|\{n_i\}\rangle\langle \{n_i\}|e^{i H}|\{n_j\}\rangle\langle \{n_i\}|0\rangle$. I did this, but I can only sum the infinite series if I can decompose $\langle \{n_i\}|0\rangle=\langle n_1|0\rangle\dots \langle n_N|0\rangle$ (note: $\langle n_i=0|0\rangle\neq 1$!).

Comment: It’s a pity you chose not to expand your answer and the linked references are quite good.

Comment: The matrix $h_{ab}$ in the phase space ($\vec{q},\vec{p}$) above defined by LFH has all the info of the evolution of the system. In the Heisenberg picture, the formal solution of your evolution equation is $\vec{\xi}(t)=U(t) \vec{\xi}(0)$ with $U(t)=exp(\int_{0}^{t} h_{ab}(t') dt')$. The propagator $U(t)$ is a symplectic matrix and can be diagonalized by a Bloch-Messiah decomposition $U=R_{1} K R_{2}$ with $R_{1,2}$ symplectic and orthogonal and $K$ diagonal and real. All the valuable info for Gaussian states is in the covariance matrix $V$. Here you obtain it as $V(t)=U(t) V(0) U^{T}(t)$.

Comment: Since your input state is vacuum $V(0)=\text{diag}(1)$ (and a factor with the value of your shot noise. I think in LFH's notation is 1/2). If you apply the Bloch-Messiah decomposition you get $V(t)=R_{1} K^{2} R_{1}^{T}$. Thus, the covariance matrix in the diagonal basis is $K^{2}(t)$ and the covariance matrix in the original basis is $V(t)$. (For experimentalists: both covariance matrices can be measured if you have an appropriate setup. It is not only a mathematical trick.) From the covariance matrix you can also retrieve the Wigner function and from it the wavefunction up to a sign.

Comment: Physically (in quantum optics) $K^{2}(t)$ represents N independently squeezed modes and $V(t)$ these squeezed modes propagating in a N-port multimode interferometer given by $R_{1}$ (https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9904002).

Comment: Hi LFH. You can have a look to this paper on multimode squeezing: https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.41.4625             In section IV they claim there is a unique solution for the time evolution operator for a general N-mode quadratic Hamiltonian (Eqs 4.21 and 4.22). It is not in arXiv, sorry. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Because I was hoping to get some standard reference, which treats this case, I thought it would be best to keep the question brief.However, as I received a lot of partial suggestions, let me try to explain my thoughts, so far. **If you know some standard reference, which treats the general case, it would be greatly appreciated!**

For this, let us introduce a basis $\hat{\xi}^a\equiv(\hat{q}_1,\hat{p}_1,\dots,\hat{q}_N,\hat{p}_N)$. With this, we can write
\begin{align}
\hat{H}=\frac{1}{2}h_{ab}\hat{\xi}^a\hat{\xi}^b\,,
\end{align}
where $h_{ab}$ is symmetric and real. It can be constructed from the matrices $A$ and $B$ from the question, but it is useful to write everything in this real basis. Note that $\hat{q}_i=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\hat{a}_i^\dagger+\hat{a}_i)$ and $\hat{p}_i=\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}(\hat{a}_i^\dagger-\hat{a}_i)$, such that $\hat{q}_i$ and $\hat{p}_j$ satisfy canonical commutation relations. We can write the commutation relations as $[\hat{\xi}^a,\hat{\xi}^b]=i\Omega^{ab}$, where $\Omega^{ab}$ is a symplectic form.

We can now define the symplectic transformation $M=e^{K}$ with $K^a{}_b=\Omega^{ac}h_{cb}$ which implements the transformation $U=e^{-i\hat{H}}$ as Bogoliubov transformation, namely
\begin{align}
U^\dagger \hat{\xi}^a U=M^a{}_b\hat{\xi}^b\,.
\end{align}
We can further use a polar decomposition (or Cartan decomposition) of $M=Tu$, where $T=\sqrt{MM^\intercal}$, which is well-defined due to $MM^\intercal>0$, and $u=T^{-1}M$. It is further easy to show that $uu^\intercal=1$. We can define $X=\log{T}$ and $Z=\log{u}$. Using the inverse symplectic form $\Omega^{-1}_{ab}$ with $\Omega^{ac}\Omega^{-1}_{cb}=\delta^a{}_b$, we can define two new quadratic Hamiltonians
\begin{align}
\widehat{X}&=\frac{1}{2}\Omega^{-1}_{ac}X^c{}_b\,\hat{\xi}^a\hat{\xi}^b\,,\\
\widehat{Y}&=\frac{1}{2}\Omega^{-1}_{ac}Z^c{}_b\,\hat{\xi}^a\hat{\xi}^b\,.
\end{align}
Using the representation theory of exponential of quadratic Hamiltonians, one can show that we have $e^{-i\hat{H}}=\pm e^{-i\widehat{X}}e^{-i\widehat{Y}}$. Furthermore, one can show that $|0\rangle$ is the ground state of $\widehat{Y}$ and that the expectation value $\langle 0|e^{-i\widehat{X}}|0\rangle$ is real, positive and can be expressed in terms of the spectrum of the matrix $T$, which itself has positive real spectrum (see below). The ground state energy $\widehat{Y}$ is also easily computed from the spectrum of $Y$, which has purely imaginary spectrum, namely the ground state energy is given by $\mathrm{Tr}(\Omega \log{u})/4$.

This gives overall the solution:
\begin{align}
\langle 0| e^{-i\hat{H}}|0\rangle=\pm e^{-i\langle 0|\hat{Y}|0\rangle} \det\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}T^{1/2}}{\sqrt{1+T^2}}\right)=\pm e^{-i\mathrm{Tr}(\Omega \log{u})/4}\det\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}T^{1/2}}{\sqrt{1+T^2}}\right)\,,
\end{align}
where we can bring $T$ into diagonal form $T=\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1,1/\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_N,1/\lambda_N)$ with $\lambda_i>0$.

This means my only trouble is the prefactor $\pm$, which is due to the fact that the exponential of quadratic Hamiltonians only form a projective representation of the symplectic group, i.e., $U(M_1)U(M_2)=\pm U(M_1M_2)$.

Comment: I realized that the subtlety of the sign corresponds to lifting the path $e^{tK}$ for a symplectic Lie algebra element $K\in\mathfrak{sp}(2N,\mathbb{R})$ from the symplectic group to the metaplectic group or - more generally - to its universal cover.

I would still be very excited to see if there is an easier way (used in quantum optics etc.), but I also rephrased the question in more mathematical language on mathoverflow (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/357755/lifting-one-parameter-subgroup-et-k-to-the-universal-cover-of-mathrmsp).

Comment: What happens if you try to transform this into the basis where $H$ is diagonal (i.e. decoupled harmonic oscillators) and |0> becomes some other state?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I tried this based on the suggestions of Daniel. First, not all quadratic Hamiltonians are diagonalizable (in general, one would need to Jordan-decompose the matrix $K$ - only if $K$ is purely imaginary, $\hat{H}$ is diagonalizable). But even if we assume that it is diagonalizable, the state $|0\rangle$ will in general be entangled over the eigenmodes of the Hamiltonian, which makes it very difficult to sum expressions. If we assume that $|0\rangle$ is not entangled between eigenmodes, I could get an analytical expression.